# Create table in MySQL based on reflected metadata from MSSQL using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy to copy table schemas between different rdbms - in this example from MSSQL to MySQL.

Is there a way to take a table object and copy and convert the metadata to a different dialect?

I tried the tometadata() function but the type info for the columns remains in the original mssql dialect.

It works ok as long as the column types are compatible, but breaks when the column type doesn't exist in MySQL eg. uniqueidentifier, varchar(max), etc

```
    import sqlalchemy as sa

    # Source table details
    source_table_name = 'Customer'
    source_schema_name = 'AdventureWorksLT2008.SalesLT'

    db_uri_mssql = "mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{dsn}"
    db_uri_mysql = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}"

    source_db = db_uri_mssql.format(user=source_user, password=source_password, dsn=source_dsn)
    target_db = db_uri_mysql.format(user=target_user, password=target_password, \
                                    host=target_host, db=target_db, port=target_port)

    source_engine = sa.create_engine(source_db, echo=False, convert_unicode=True, legacy_schema_aliasing=False)
    target_engine = sa.create_engine(target_db, echo=False, convert_unicode=True)

    source_meta = sa.MetaData(bind=source_engine)
    target_meta = sa.MetaData(bind=target_engine)

    source_table = sa.Table(source_table_name, source_meta, autoload=True, schema=source_schema_name)

    target_table = source_table.tometadata(target_meta, schema=None)

    target_table.create(target_engine, checkfirst=True)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/josh/PycharmProjects/Dmigrate3/Dmigrate3.py", line 38, in 
    target_table.create(target_engine, checkfirst=True)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 725, in create
    checkfirst=checkfirst)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1854, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1481, in _run_visitor
    **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 764, in visit_table
    include_foreign_key_constraints=include_foreign_key_constraints
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 68, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 962, in _execute_ddl
    compiled = ddl.compile(dialect=dialect)
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 494, in compile
    return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 26, in _compiler
    return dialect.ddl_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 190, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 213, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2167, in visit_create_table
    (table.description, column.name, ce.args[0])
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2156, in visit_create_table
    and not first_pk)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 213, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2187, in visit_create_column
    first_pk=first_pk
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1954, in get_column_specification
    column.type, type_expression=column)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 261, in process
    return type_._compiler_dispatch(self, **kw)
  File "/Users/josh/Dmig3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 79, in _compiler_dispatch
    raise exc.UnsupportedCompilationError(visitor, cls)
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'Customer', column 'rowguid'): Compiler  can't render element of type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way or the other you actually need to define equivalent type in the target RDBMS for each of those that cannot be mapped automatically.

One way to achieve this would be to define your own compiles extension:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, VARCHAR

@compiles(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 'mysql')
def compile_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_mssql_mysql(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ Handles mssql UNIQUEIDENTIFIER datatype as VARCHAR in MySQL """
    try: 
        length = element.length
    except:
        length = None
    element.length = 64 # @note: 36 should be enough, but see the link below

    # @note: since SA-0.9 all string types have collation, which are not 
    # really compatible between databases, so use default one
    element.collation = None

    res = compiler.visit_VARCHAR(element, **kw)
    if length: 
        element.length = length
    return res

@compiles(BIT, 'mysql')
def compile_BIT_mssql_mysql(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ Handles mssql BIT datatype as BOOLEAN in mysql """
    return compiler.visit_BOOLEAN(element, **kw)
```

And after that run your code, which hopefully will work just fine.

Note: I do not know MySQL very well, and not sure about the best mapping of the data types, but i looked [10.5.4 Microsoft SQL Server Type Mapping](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-mssql-typemapping.html) for the information.