# Convert PostgreSQL to sqlite database with SQLAlchemy in Python3

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Could it be possible to convert a postgresql database (including data) with SQLAlchemy to a sqlite database?

I tried the code below. It looks like that it works.

What do you think about it? Could this be an answer?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as sad
import sqlalchemy.orm as sao
import sqlalchemy.orm.session as sas
from sqlalchemy_utils import create_database

_Base = sad.declarative_base()

class Child(_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Child'

    _oid = sa.Column('oid', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    _name = sa.Column('name', sa.String)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name


class Parent(_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Parent'

    _oid = sa.Column('oid', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    _name = sa.Column('name', sa.String)
    _child_fk = sa.Column('child', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('Child.oid'))
    _child = sao.relationship('Child')

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Parent, self).__init__()
        self._name = name


pstr = 'postgres://postgres@localhost/Family'
sstr = 'sqlite:///family.db'

pengine = sa.create_engine(pstr, echo = True)
sengine = sa.create_engine(sstr, echo = True)

def createPostgreSQL_Family():
    """Create for PostgreSQL the scheme and the data for testing."""

    # create schema
    create_database(pengine.url)
    _Base.metadata.create_all(pengine)
    psession = sao.sessionmaker(bind = pengine)()

    # child
    c = Child('Jim Bob')
    psession.add(c)
    psession.commit()

    # parent
    p = Parent('Mr. Doe')
    p._child = c
    psession.add(p)
    psession.commit()

    psession.close()

def convert():
    # get one object from the PostgreSQL database
    psession = sao.sessionmaker(bind = pengine)()

    p = psession.query(Parent).first()
    sas.make_transient(p)
    #p._oid = None

    c = psession.query(Child).first()
    sas.make_transient(c)
    #c._oid = None

    psession.close()

    # create and open the SQLite database
    create_database(sengine.url)
    _Base.metadata.create_all(sengine)

    # add/convert the one object to the new database
    ssession = sao.sessionmaker(bind = sengine)()

    ssession.add(c)
    ssession.add(p)
    ssession.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #createPostgreSQL_Family()
    convert()
```

Comment: database schema? or actual data as well?

Comment: then you probably should look at solutions of type 'dump db', then 'load db'

Comment: This isnt a solution because I have to modify the dump file myself. Maybe sqla can do this conversion for me. Please keep in mind this question is sqla specific.

Comment: I know it is not a solution. It is therefore a comment. In any case, see this question/answer in case you have to *migrate* db schema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949802/create-table-in-mysql-based-on-reflected-metadata-from-mssql-using-sqlalchemy. And in order to copy data, you really have to do some work: iterate over table in the proper order (in case you care about ForeignKeys), select data (probably in chunks) from those tables (usually as list of dictionaries), and then perform `insert` on the target database/table. It is labour intensive to get this right universally though.